# Internal opensource web-based office solution

Tags: open-source, microsoft-office

I am looking for an open source equivalent to Google Docs that can be locally hosted. Does anyone have any experience in using any open source web office solutions?

The key features I am looking for are

- Runs on Linux
- Supports importing .xls spreadsheets
- Easy to setup
- Intuitive interface

Answer (score 1):

[www.opengoo.org](http://www.opengoo.org) is a project striving to recreate much of the Google Docs experience (including mail integration).

I'm not sure about the importing of XLS documents.  I haven't quite made it that deep into the demo.

Comment: I came across this but web-based spreadsheets seem to still be under development.